# Redirect sendmail to page instead of error message

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email, redirect

I've tried so many variables and been at this for hours and hours for something I know will be so simple haha, but I cannot get this to work... All I need to do, is... when the form is completed I have it redirected to a page instead of the normal error message.

Your help is appreciated.

```
<?php
//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$phone = ($_GET['phone']) ? $_GET['phone'] : $_POST['phone'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$comment = ($_GET['comment']) ?$_GET['comment'] : $_POST['comment'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1

if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$phone) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your contact number.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$comment) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your comment.'; 

//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {

    //recipient - replace your email here
    $to = 'me@myemail.com'; 
    //sender - from the form
    $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message
    $subject = 'Message from ' . $name; 
    $message = 'Name: ' . $name . '<br/><br/>
                Phone: ' . $phone . '<br/><br/>
                Email: ' . $email . '<br/><br/>     
                Message: ' . nl2br($comment) . '<br/>';

    //send the mail
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

    //if POST was used, display the message straight away
    if ($_POST) {
        if ($result) 
            echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
        else 
            echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

        //else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
            //ajax script can react accordingly
            //1 means success, 0 means failed
    } else {
        echo $result;   
    }

    //if the errors array has values
} else {
    //display the errors message
    for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
    echo '<a href="index.html">Back</a>';
    exit;
}


//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if ($result) 
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if ($result) { header('Location: thanks.php'); } else { header('Location: error.php'); } exit;`

Comment: Maybe I can take the opertunity to introduce you to the [`$_REQUEST` array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: AND: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @mistermartin thank for the line of code... I'm a PHP/Javascript extreme novice. I tried implementing the code in various areas and overwriting some code to put it in it's place, but it is still not working. any suggestions?

Comment: @RiggsFolly apologies for what appears to be a messy code, I simply copied and pasted from my workspace. as for the $_REQUEST, I will have to take my time to not only read it, but also understand it... unfortunately for me, reading that code is like reading Chinese :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I've decided to go with the standard code with a few modifications.. again thanks for your input.. cheers